# OTA update to kivy Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to give an OTA Update for my Kivy GUI Project. Is there there any Package or tutorial where i can learn. If any one have example of it, provide link of it.
I am using Python 3.5 and run it on Window PC.
I am not gonna use any `Arduino` or any other electric component. I want to give update from web servers. I don't know the concept of OTA Update. If it is not possible using OTA then give me another way to update the GUI online, where i can change some values from web servers or site and my GUI change automatically.

Comment: Have you tried Simblee for the same. Catch up this blog:http://www.mblabs.org/blog/    ... Hope it helps

Comment: i am run that GUI in my Windows PC not in arduino, Raspberry Pi and stuff like that.